# Output of piped processes not exactly as expected. Why? (C, UNIX)

Tags: c, unix, process, pipe

The purpose of the following code is to create 2 children processes. One of which will execute 'ls'. The other will execute 'sort' using the output of 'ls'. Both children processes are piped to achieve this. The code works, however, the output formatting is not exactly what I expected.

Code: minishell.c

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <unistd.h>
 #include <sys/wait.h>

`int main()
 {  
    int fd[2];
    pipe(fd);`

    //First child process created: ls 
    if (fork() == 0) {
        /*child */
        close(fd[0]);
        dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(fd[1]);
        execlp("ls", "ls", (char *)0);
            fprintf(stderr, "execlp(ls) failed\n");
            exit(1);
        }

    wait(NULL);

    //Second child process created: sort
    if (fork() == 0) {
        close(fd[1]);
        dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        close(fd[0]);
        execlp("sort", "sort", (char *)0);
        fprintf(stderr, "execlp(sort) failed\n");
        exit(1);
        }   

    close(fd[0]);
    close(fd[1]);

    wait(NULL);
    fprintf(stderr, "parent done\n");

    return 0;

}
```

Expected output: **ls | sort**

```
8.bmp       bmplib.h      Downloads/   lab4.c       Music/     tester
appData/    bmptool.c     example.bmp  Makefile     myls.c     testfile.c
bitcount.c  Documents/    infile       minishell.c  Pictures/  Videos/
bitcount*   Desktop/      fork.c       minishell*   myshell.c  Testfile.txt
bmplib.c    doublefork.c  lab4*        Movies/      temp/
```

My output: **./minishell**

```
8.bmp
appData
bitcount
bitcount.c
bmplib.c
bmplib.h
bmptool.c
Desktop
Documents
doublefork.c
Downloads
example.bmp
fork.c
infile
lab4
lab4.c
Makefile
minishell
minishell.c
Movies
Music
myls.c
myshell.c
Pictures
temp
tester
testfile.c
Testfile.txt
Videos
parent done
```

1. Why is the formatting different between the two cases?
2. Why are '/' removed from all folder names in the case of ./minishell?
3. In the case of **ls | sort**, why do some folders show up before some files ('Pictures/' before 'myshell.c'; 'Videos/' before 'Testfile.txt') when this is clearly not in accordance with lexicographical order?

*I tried testing with **ls -l | sort**, and then **./minishell** (after adding "-l" to execlp of the first child of course), and the outputs were identical except for '/' being removed from each folder name.

My hypothesis is that it has something to do with the pipe. I think that both processes, 'ls' and 'sort' in isolation work fine. However, something goes bad when one of then writes to/reads from the pipe. I have tried really hard to find the underlying problem to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

the output is fine, try switching terminals, side note 42sh is way harder than minishell, don't over achieve on minishell cause 42sh you gonna have to do alot of reworks.